# Birt Barcode Plugin slows PDF creation by 6s?

Tags: pdf, barcode, birt

I have a BIRT template which contains a barcode element. Removing this element changes the time it takes to generate a PDF from ~6 to 0,3 seconds.

```
<cell id="7689">
    <property name="paddingTop">0pt</property>
    <property name="paddingLeft">0pt</property>
    <property name="paddingBottom">0pt</property>
    <property name="paddingRight">0pt</property>
    <extended-item extensionName="Barcode" id="7972">
        <property name="barcodeType">6</property>
        <expression name="data">row["barcode"]</expression>
        <property name="supSpace">10.0</property>
        <property name="msiCheckSumType">0</property>
        <property name="dmDataMode">0</property>
        <property name="dmFormatMode">0</property>
        <property name="dmFNC1Mode">0</property>
        <property name="pdfDataMode">0</property>
        <property name="pdfEcl">2</property>
        <property name="pdfRowCount">0</property>
        <property name="pdfXYRatio">1.0</property>
        <property name="qrDataMode">0</property>
        <property name="qrEcl">0</property>
        <property name="qrVersion">0</property>
        <property name="uom">2</property>
        <property name="xModule">11.0</property>
        <property name="yModule">20.0</property>
        <property name="leftMargin">0.0</property>
        <property name="rightMargin">0.0</property>
        <property name="topMargin">0.0</property>
        <property name="resolution">100</property>
        <property name="showText">0</property>
        <property name="marginLeft">8pt</property>
        <property name="height">11mm</property>
        <property name="width">11mm</property>
    </extended-item>
</cell>
```

There seems to be no newer version of the plugin, but this delay is totally inacceptable. Am I using it wrong? Where could I make changes to increase performance while using a barcode element?

Edit: putting it this way performs well ( <0,5s ):

```
<extended-item extensionName="Barcode" id="8675">
    <property name="barcodeType">20</property>
    <expression name="data">row["barcode"]</expression>
    <property name="marginLeft">8pt</property>
    <property name="height">11mm</property>
    <property name="width">11mm</property>
</extended-item>
```

Using BIRT 4.4.1 and Onbarcode Plugin 2.2.1

Comment: Does the issue happens only when exporting to pdf? Or also when displaying as html or exporting to word?

Comment: the performance is also low when exporting to Word or HTML